# Transferred from -oh-my-zsh to prezto but nothing seems to be working?

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Just transferred from oh-my zsh to prezto but I can't seem to get anything working unfortunately.
eg presto commands like: prompt -l (to see themes don't seem to work).
(I have my .Z----- files setup and symlinked)
Also which prezto returns not found.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by deleting the `.zshrc` file and reinstalling.